# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, typeerror

### Problem is that when i press selector to select continents its gives me this error /Search buy the way works fine only problem is with selector it maybe due to me using react-router-domV6 and Axios don't know

Search works well buy the way
Thanks in advance
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/US56E.png

Controls.jsx

```
        import React from 'react';
        import { Search } from './Search';
        import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
        import {CustomSelect} from './CustomSelect';
        import styled from 'styled-components';
        const options=
       [
         {value: 'Америка',label: 'Америка'},
         {value: 'Європа',label: 'Європа'},
         {value: 'Азія',label: 'Азія'},
         {value: 'Африка',label: 'Африка'},
         {value: 'Океанія',label: 'Океанія'},
         {value: 'Австралія',label: 'Австралія'},
       ];
       const Wrapper=styled.div`
       display:flex;
       flex-direction:column;
       align-items:flex-start;
        @media (min-width: 768px) 
       {
         flex-direction:row;
         justify-content:space-between;
         align-items:center;
        }
       `;
         export const Controls = ({onSearch}) => {
          const [search,setSearch]=useState('');
          const [region,setRegion]=useState('');
          useEffect(()=>{
           const regionValue = region?.value;
           onSearch(search,regionValue);
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          },[search,region]);

        return (
         <Wrapper>
          <Search search={search} setSearch={setSearch}/>
           <CustomSelect
         options={options}
         placeholder='Континент'
         isClearable
         isSearchable={false}
         value={region}
         onChange={setRegion}
          />
        </Wrapper>
        );
      };
```

HomePage.jsx

```
     import React from 'react';
     import axios from 'axios';
     import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
     import { useNavigate,useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
     import { Main } from '../components/Main';
     import { Controls } from '../components/Controls';
     import { ALL_COUNTRIES } from '../config';
     import { List } from '../components/List';
     import { Card } from '../components/Card';
     import { Details } from './Details';

      export const HomePage = ({countries,setCountries}) => {
       const [filteredCountries,setFilteredCountries] = useState(countries);
       const  navigate  = useNavigate();
       const handleSearch =(search,region)=>{
       let data=[...countries];
       if(region){
        data=data.filter(c=>c.region.includes(region))
        }
        if(search){
          data=data.filter(c=>c.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
        }
        setFilteredCountries(data);
        };
       useEffect(() => {
      if(!countries.lenght)
       axios.get(ALL_COUNTRIES).then(
        ({data})=>setCountries(data))
        .then(result => result.json)
        },[]);
        return (
         <>
           <Controls onSearch={handleSearch}/>
           <List>
        {
          filteredCountries.map((c)=>
          {
            const countryInfo={
              img:c.flags.png,
              name:c.name,
              info: [
                {
                  title:'Population',
                  description:c.population.toLocaleString(),
                },
                {
                  title:'Region',
                  description:c.region,
                },
                {
                  title:'Flag',
                  description:c.capital,
                },
              ],

             };
               return <Card key={c.name} onClick={(e)=>{navigate(`/country/${c.name}`)}} 
            {...countryInfo}/>
            })
           }
           </List>
           </>
           );
          };
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setCountries` function is a void return. It doesn't return anything for the next then-able of the Promise chain. If `countries` is an array then you've also a typo access the array length property.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!countries.lenght) // countries.lenght is false so resolves true always
    axios.get(ALL_COUNTRIES)
      .then(({ data }) => setCountries(data)) // setCountries returns undefined
      .then(result => result.json) // result is undefined
}, []);
```

Perhaps you meant to check the length and then return the JSON Promise

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!countries.length) {
    axios.get(ALL_COUNTRIES)
      .then(result => result.json()) // <-- invoke json()
      .then(({ data }) => setCountries(data));
  }
}, []);
```

If I'm not mistaken though, the `axios` function returns the JSON response data "unpacked" already, so the `result.json()` call may not be necessary.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!countries.length) {
    axios.get(ALL_COUNTRIES)
      .then(({ data }) => setCountries(data));
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: if (!countries.length) is used to optimize process when i click on elements it redirects me to different page this (if) allows not to load page again and again  also about axios you are right but your proposal didn't work regardless  of that

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I just split `useEffect` for Search and Selector

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!countries.length)
        axios.get(ALL_COUNTRIES).then(({ data }) => setCountries(data));
   // eslint-disable-next-line
}, []);


useEffect(() => {
    handleSearch();
  // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [countries]);
```

maybe it was due to `useEffect` limitation